# How to get Access Token and Access Token Secret from Magento 1.7 REST API

Tags: php, api, magento, rest, magento-1.7

I've registered my application on my magento admin.

already got the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.

but i have no luck to get the access token and access token secret.

it said

> oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key

[image: Simple REST API]

i'm testing based on this link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html

What i need to know the answer is

1. What must i fill to Header & Data textfield?
2. How to get the Access Token and Access Secret Token (on Mozilla)?
3. Is there any tutorial step by step to test any REST API?

Comment: have you find solution for this question

Comment: yes i found the solution chanz

Comment: @Josua Marcel Chrisano: Can you please send me the link for the solution by using RESTClient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**0) Install https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo to your chrome**

**1) Get an oAuth client tool with command :**

```
sudo gem install oauth
```

**2) Set up the Magento server**

**3) Get the oAuth tokens**

```
oauth \
  --verbose \
   --query-string \
   --consumer-key v484mnii2jyswedm6uo2cfcjay7uy49snws \
   --consumer-secret koay6845che7giy5lr17gnrhckkbhf8h5 \
   --access-token-url http://www.yourstore.com/magento/oauth/token \
   --authorize-url http://www.yourstore.com/magento/oauth/authorize \
   --request-token-url http://www.yourstore.com/magento/oauth/initiate \
   authorize
```

RESPOND :

```
Server appears to support OAuth 1.0a; enabling support.
Please visit this url to authorize:
http://www.yourstore.com/magento/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=ey6fokp0pbzwr1016eb528y5xw1ak5ji

Please enter the verification code provided by the SP (oauth_verifier):
YOUR_CODE_HERE

Response:
  oauth_token_secret: g9kyz8c7zv868d58eav1muih3gxvq763
  oauth_token: aqvlfv9tuexn0mqiydgkaff4ixxg8743c
```

**4) Make the API call**

```
oauth \
    --consumer-key v484mnii2jyswedm6uo2cfcjay7uy49snws \
    --consumer-secret koay6845che7giy5lr17gnrhckkbhf8h5 \ 
    --token aqvlfv9tuexn0mqiydgkaff4ixxg8743c \
    --secret g9kyz8c7zv868d58eav1muih3gxvq763 \ 
    --uri http://www.yourstore.com/magento/api/rest/products \
    debug
```

try `http://www.yourstore.com/magento/api/rest/products`

---

**Found it the solution**

> http://www.aschroder.com/2012/04/introduction-to-the-magento-rest-apis-with-oauth-in-version-1-7/

for php

> https://gist.github.com/2469319

Comment: How are you making an API call with all those parameters? using line by line inside command line interface by starting oauth gem? or its just a one long string that I would have to enter on the command line?