# How to get oauth_access token and secret in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, rest, magento-1.7

I'm new to Magento. I want to make connection to Magento using REST API. I've founded Consumer Key & Consumer Secret. But I don't know how to find oauth_access token & secret in Magento 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Please create an initial call using consumer key and consumer secret and Magento will answer with an URL, where you will find the required data.

Please look on this answer: [How to get Access Token and Access Token Secret from Magento 1.7 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263343/how-to-get-access-token-and-access-token-secret-from-magento-1-7-rest-api)